how to set checkpoint with efficientdet model and tensorflow object detection API
I have run the training process, but for the evaluation I run only at the last checkpoint step, can someone help me to provide input so that I can change the checkpoint assignment per 100 steps, so that the graph of the evaluation appears on tensorboard
tried evaluating per 100 steps, but it still evaluates at the last checkpoint, even though I have tried using save_checkpoints_steps, but it is not supported, I don't know why
